# Проверка валидности url

Tags: валидация

Всем привет! Интересует следующий вопрос: можно ли проверить введена в поле ввода ссылка или обычный текст без регулярных выражений?

Comment: В какое поле ввода? Проверить на каком языке программирования? Чем регулярные выражения не устроили?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @andreymal. На чём пишите?

Comment: Передаём текст браузеру и ждём. Если получаем страницу - ссылка, если матюги - текст.